# ElasticSearch: Use Query to get single document ranking

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use ElasticSearch to compute a ranking. I'm not sure if this is possible and am trying to find out what my options might be. I need to run a query on all documents, sort them descending and then just return what number position in the list a specific record is located.

For example, I want to find out Julie's class ranking. I have records of each student in Julie's grade that contains their names and GPA's and I want to perform 1 query that will tell me what her rank in within her grade.

I am hoping there is an ES guru out there that can help because otherwise I am going to need to run a regular query, get back max 10,000 records and figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be found in a single query.

First you need to get GPA of "Julia" and then find count of docs which have score higher than Julia.

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "gpa": {
        "gt": 8 --> GPA of julia
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "name.keyword" --> count where gpa is greater than 8
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Better option is to store rank in document itself while indexing